# Do all Marvel Films have a second, non-foreshadowing post-credits scene?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers

I was watching The Avengers last night (26th April 2015) on 7Mate on Australian Television. When I first saw the film in the theater I didn't know who Thanos was or the meaning behind the post-credits scene, but now knowing I was expecting to see it in a new light.

After the credits however there was a different scene. The Avengers (including Thor) were in a restaurant, possibly in New York given its state, eating burgers... that's it. No Thanos, no dialogue, no nothing.

Then I remembered Iron Man 3; post-credits I was expecting maybe a hint of Ultron, however it was just Tony lounging back as if he was having a therapy session (he interrupts the guy who tried to explain he wasn't a therapist).

This got me wondering, do all the Marvel Films have a second post-credit scene which doesn't have any hints to future films? If so, why even have it in there?

Comment: “After the credits however there was a different scene. The Avengers (including Thor) were in a restaurant, possibly in New York given its state, eating burgers... that's it. No Thanos, no dialogue, no nothing.” — Yup. Thanos appears in the *mid-credits* scene in Avengers, and Avengers 2. (Plus in the actual movie in *Guardians of the Galaxy*.)

Comment: “he interrupts the guy who tried to explain he wasn't a therapist” — specifically, Bruce Banner.

Comment: Oh, and: “eating burgers” — nope. Eating [shawarma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawarma), as Tony suggested near the end of the film.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a pretty solid list on the Fandom page [List of Post-credits Scenes](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Post-credits_Scenes) that you can refer to. In short, the latest films in the MCU series seem to have a *secondary* post-credit-scene whereas the earlier films had only one scene after the credits.

Based on current trends, I look forward to future films containing less than a minute of *actual* film and no less than 90 post-credit scenes by the year 2040.

---

As to why they have a [stinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-credits_scene) at all, the best answer is that it's a nifty way to get you to sit through the credits instead of simply leaving the cinema and ignoring all the people who worked hard to make the film you just enjoyed.

Comment: Seeing the list it seems i was mistaken. i thought the second scene at Shawarma Palace replaced the original one with Thanos. i must have missed the Thanos Scene on TV due to being called up for tech support and i must have missed the  Shawarma Palace scene originally having left too early

Comment: “I look forward to future films containing less than a minute of actual film and no less than 90 post-credit scenes by the year 2040” — Guardians 2 got us on the way!

Comment: True, this way you ignore all the people who worked hard to make the film you just enjoyed while sitting on the cinema waiting for the post scene.

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba - I enjoyed a meal at a restaurant yesterday. Instead of bringing me the bill, they insisted on me staying while they introduced me to every single member of their team and the cleaning staff.

Comment: The film was released to movie theatres in Australia without the shawarma shop scene - apparently production of the scene was not finished in time for the Australian release. The film was released the following week in the USA with the scene added.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite refers to https://xkcd.com/605/

Comment: @b_jonas - The next GotG film will have ten post-credit scenes.

Comment: "ignoring all the people who worked hard to make the film you just enjoyed." You presume that people actually look at the names and aren't busy getting their coats, figuring out where to lose their cell phones, stepping _over_ the spilled pop corn and slurping down the rest of their Coke?

Answer (score 14):

In detail:

- Four MCU films have a pre-credits stinger scene:

  - *The Incredible Hulk*
  - *Guardians of the Galaxy*
  - *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*
  - *Black Widow*
- Most MCU films from *The Avengers* onwards have one mid-credits scene (i.e. a scene between the fancy animated credits and the regular white-text-on-black credits). The exceptions are:

  - *Iron Man 3*
  - *Guardians of the Galaxy*
  - *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* (which makes up for its predecessor with *three* scenes sprinkled throughout its entirely-animated credits)
  - *Avengers: Infinity War*
  - *Avengers: Endgame*
  - *Black Widow*
- Every MCU film has a post-credits scene, except for:

  - *The Incredible Hulk*
  - *Avengers: Age of Ultron*
  - *Avengers: Endgame* (unless you count [some enigmatic audio](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/210743/what-s-with-the-clanks-at-the-end-of-the-credits-in-avengers-endgame); or the Stan Lee tribute, deleted Hulk scene, and *Far From Home* sneak peek added to the re-release)

Most of these 51 scenes *do* foreshadow future movies (or seem to), regardless of their position, but most of the thirteen I'd count as primarily comedy are post-credits:

- Avengers
- Iron Man 3
- Thor: The Dark World
- Guardians of the Galaxy
- Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2
- Spider-Man: Homecoming
- Thor: Ragnarok
- Ant-Man and the Wasp
- Captain Marvel
- Doctor Strange: it's a Mad, Mad, Mad, Mad Multiverse

(The others are the Groot pre- and mid-credit scenes in *Guardians* 1 and 2 respectively, and the *Guardians 2* pre-credit scene with Kraglin and Drax.  The notable non-foreshadowing, non-comedy exception is *Black Panther’s* mid-credits scene, which plays more like a heartfelt statement in favour of co-operation between nations.)

But most absolutely tease future movies —  both *Captain America: The First Avenger* and *Spider-Man: No Way Home* effectively have full-on teaser trailers for the next MCU movie as their post-credits scenes.

As to why even have scenes in there if they don't hint about future films — how about entertainment? Can't we have things in our comic book movies that are just for fun?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't the incredible hulk scene of stark meeting ross and the guardians scene with howard the duck both post credits?

Comment: @WizardKnight: “correct me if I'm wrong” — I thought Christmas was over! The Howard the Duck scene in *Guardians* is indeed post-credits. It also has a teeny Groot dancing to the Jackson 5 pre-credits, but nothing mid-credits.  I’m pretty sure the *Incredible Hulk* Stark/Ross scene is pre-credits, but I’ll double-check.

Comment: @WizardKnight: eyup. Hulk’s scene is pre-credits, at least on my iTunes copy.