# How long has Talos been on Earth impersonating this character?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

During the end credit scene of *Spider-Man: Far from Home*, we see that,

> Nick Fury and Maria Hill are two Skrulls, Talos and (presumably) his wife.

And we also see that,

> Nick Fury is in a spaceship like structure, presumably away from Earth.

So that begs the question,

> How long has Talos been impersonating Nick Fury? Is it since the events of *Captain Marvel* or since *Avengers: Endgame* or sometime in between?

Comment: This is surely a hook into MCU's next phase, where we can expect a script arc about skrull invasion

Comment: @Bardo: possibly, although Talos and Soren very much seem to be working on behalf of Fury, with him perhaps nominally in command of a Skull ship. Also, [the post-credit scenes have something of a trend towards comedy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87312/do-all-marvel-films-have-a-second-non-foreshadowing-post-credits-scene/145268#145268).

Comment: Also makes me wonder what Hill was doing during this time...

Comment: What if.. Talos has been impersonating Fury since 1995 right after he lost his eye  so, Talos created the Avengers and he’s always been the one who took all the major decisions throughout the 10+ year MCU saga  #mindblown

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It was the real Fury at the end of *Avengers: Endgame* at Tony's funeral. The director, Jon Watts, told this to Slash Film:

> **How long has Talos been impersonating Fury before this film begins, and can you talk me through the decision to have a Skrull play Fury in your movie?**
>
> In my mind, Talos has only been Fury from the beginning of this movie. That was real Nick Fury at Tony’s funeral…unless someone else tells me otherwise. I don’t want to get in too deep with that stuff. After I saw *Captain Marvel*, and really seeing so much more of Nick Fury’s origin story, it only made sense for us in this sort of con man story that we’re telling, to keep that on the table as just one last opportunity for a big reversal that makes you watch the whole movie in a different way.
>
> <sub>[Slash Film, ‘Spider-Man: Far From Home’ Spoilers: Director Jon Watts on the Post-Credits Scene, the Song He Wrote for the Film, and More [Interview]](https://www.slashfilm.com/spider-man-far-from-home-spoiler-interview/)</sub>

It appears that sometime after the funeral Fury went up into space for a "holiday" and Talos, and his wife, impersonated him to cover for him. The timeline on how long after the Blip is unclear.

It is also unclear how many times, if at all, Talos and Fury have switched places in the past.

This could explain how Fury was able to eat diagonally cut toast in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* as explained in *Captain Marvel* apparently he couldn't. However, that might be reading too much into the film but it is up to you to decide if that was a filming mistake or Talos as Fury.

[image: Fury eats diagonally cut toast]

Comment: That doesn't totally make sense, since Talos (presumably) in Far From Home says "I saw you at the funeral". Unless, he's just doing a really good job impersonating Fury--which could be possible.

Comment: @Chipster that’s literally what they do and Skrulls inherit the persons recent memories so seems like he does remember it.

Comment: “This could explain how Fury was able to eat diagonally cut toast in *Avengers: Age of *Ultron” — I like to think that, one day, we’ll get an intense training montage sequence of Fury forcing himself out of his diagonal toast aversion.

Comment: Was he eating diagonally-cut toast or diagonally-cut bread in *Ultron*?  The internet seems divided on the subject.